# Openfire server is not starting on JAVA 64 bit

Tags: java, openfire

i was trying to install openfire in my windows 64 bit OS, but server was not starting , and giving below error message.

which says JAVA_HOME doesn't point to 32 bit JRE,

[image: 32 jdk issue]

where as in openfire site, nothing was said about 32 or 64 bit jdk version.

upon clicking ok i am getting serious of error messages,

[image: error message 2]

[image: error message 3]

do i need to point openfire to 32 bit jdk and jre to make it workable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have downloaded zip version of openfire , which is having this issue, i have downloaded .exe version with jre bundled, which is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to start openfire from command line: 
`java -jar startup.jar`

Assuming it is executed from ./lib of openfire installation dir, and you have binaries of your preferred java in system path.

Answer (score 0):

The error means exactly what it said. You have either installed the wrong architecture flavor of Java / the JDK or haven't installed Java at all. If you haven't installed the 32-bit JDK yet, grab it at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and install it. If you already have the 32 Bit JDK, change the environment variables of your system to let JAVA_HOME point to the correct installation. Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/ for further instructions. If that doesn't help, deinstall every JDK inst install the 32-bit JDK from scratch.